# Building a hdf5 structure from an excel table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I am building a keylist from an Excel table:

[image: Table]

I want every key to have a 'X' and a 'Y' subgroup. Then save it to a keylist:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', usecols = ['A','B','C'])
print(df)

keylist = []
list1, list2, list3 = df['A'].tolist(), df['B'].tolist(), df['C'].tolist()

for i in zip(list1, list2):
    val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append("/".join(val) + '/X')
    val = map(str, i)
    keylist.append("/".join(val) + '/Y')

print(keylist)
```

Keylist Looks like this:

[image: Keylist]

Now I want to build a hdf5 structure from the keylist. It should look like this:

[image]

Does pd.HDFStore have an application for this?

Edit: Unfortunately we use only Pandas at my Office and not h5py to work with hdf5 files. The Solutions (h5py) provided so far do not work.

Comment: Can you provide more information on your workflow [a sentence or two would do]? Would a nested dictionary not suffice for this structure?

Comment: In the next step I want to append datasets to each key. Is that the wrong Approach?

Comment: I am having a hdf5 file and an Excel file. the Excel file holds the keys of the hdf5 datasets. I am trying to for example, sum all dataset values in a specific top Group, with the help of the keys from the Excel file.

Comment: Also, are you going to be storing pandas dataframes in leaf datasets or numerical arrays, or something else?

Comment: I do not know yet. The dataset values are floats.

Answer (score 1):

If your data consists of `float` arrays, I recommend you do *not* use `pd.HDFStore` for this.

Instead, use `h5py` which ties in well syntactically with `numpy`. Use `pandas` only for reading your Excel file. Read the [h5py documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/index.html) for how to add datasets to groups.

The benefit of this method is you will find it more efficient (`pd.HDFStore` has overheads) and transportable (your HDF5 file can be read outside of Python).

```
import pandas as pd
import h5py

df = pd.DataFrame([['blue', 'a', 'a1'], ['blue', 'a', 'a2'],
                   ['blue', 'b', 'b1'], ['red', 'c', 'c1']],
                  columns=list('ABC'))

## read in file
# df = pd.read_excel('group_file.xlsx')

## create group strings
group_strings = ['/'+'/'.join(route) for route in df.values]

# ['/blue/a/a1', '/blue/a/a2', '/blue/b/b1', '/red/c/c1']

## create HDF5 groups
with h5py.File('file.h5', 'w') as f:
    for group in group_strings:
        for item in ('X', 'Y'):
            grp = f[group+'/'+item]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately at my Office we use primarily Pandas to work with hdf5. I tried to execute your code but it Returns a KeyError: 'Unable to open object (Component not found)'. Something with "h5py\h5o.pyx" so I assume, that the h5py library is not updated. Would you provide a soltuion with Pandas.HDFStore?

Comment: OK, understood. I'll leave this answer here for the non-Office restricted.